# Stock QTY gets negative after order

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Facing issue with WooCommerce. When customers order products, the ordered products get a negative qty while backorders are disabled. For example:

Product in WooCommerce:
Product 1, QTY 10

Ordered products:
Product 1, QTY 4

After order, product in WooCommerce:
Product 1, QTY -4, Out of Stock

Anyone faced this issue before and know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

After disabling and enabling plugins I found out this issue was caused by One Click Install plugin which was provided with template.

Comment: Your answer saved me. I have faced the same issue, just fixed with the help of your answer.